# How to implement IMAP Protocol (Server side) using C#

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit, mimekit

I am trying to write a service that provide user a subdomain as mailbox.
So I need to implement IMAP server on my own.
I notice mimekit/mailkit may help me. (At least they can help me test my server.)
It is possible to implement a minimum IMAP Protocol (server side) using mimekit/mailkit?

Comment: Here is golang version of imap-server. https://github.com/jordwest/imap-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that *MimeKit* would certainly be helpful in that a significant part of writing an IMAP server (or even a POP3 or SMTP server) is that you will at some point need to deal with parsing messages and/or headers and MimeKit is a perfect solution for that.

There are *parts* of MailKit which might be helpful for implementing an IMAP server. For example, re-using the `UniqueId` (and related) classes for your IMAP server project would likely be useful. Likewise, if you eventually implement the `THREAD` extension, the `MessageThreader` class would be invaluable.

The `ImapEncoding` class would certainly be reusable.

You *might* be able to at least partially re-use the `ImapStream` (and `ImapToken`) class as your tokenizer for an IMAP server, but I'm not 100% sure on that since I've never looked at it from that perspective and there might be subtle differences there, but you could probably use it as a reasonable starting point.

`ImapUtils.FormatInternalDate()` would be a good candidate for re-use...

You might be able to reuse a lot of the `FolderQuota` and `AccessControl` classes as well if you end up supporting the `QUOTA` and/or `ACL` IMAP extensions (not that those classes do much).

I'm sure there are various other bits & pieces that would be helpful to re-use from MailKit, but you won't be able to easily turn the `ImapClient` class into an `ImapServer` class, for example.

And then, of course, as you mentioned in your post, you could always use MailKit as a great way of testing your IMAP server implementation to make sure things work.

Hope that helps answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to implement a minimum IMAP Server using mimekit/mailkit?

Short answer: No!

> The main goal of this project is to provide the .NET world with
>   robust, fully featured and RFC-compliant SMTP, POP3, and IMAP client
>   implementations.

You should beware of the huge difference between a mail server (which keeps your emails, is visible to the outside world and normally is 24/7 live) and a mail client which is mainly used to fetch the mails from that sever.

Comment: IMAP server doesn't equal to mail server. I mean just implement the IMAP protocol (server side).  I just want user can use IMAP to get the mails.